# why does my code when running using JIT in python give wrong output?

Tags: python, numba, jit

```
#!/home/fury/anaconda3/bin/python
from numba import jit
import sys
@jit(nopython=True)
def isprime(n):
    if n==2:return 1
    if n%2==0:return 0
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if n%i==0:return 0
    return 1
def main():
    print(isprime(float(sys.argv[1])))
if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

> when inputting bigger numbers with more than 22 digits it return wrong value it
> simply does a modular division wrong for example for the input: 151978145606541879151 >it's saying it is divisible by 13 while its not and it is a perfect prime.

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert input number to float. When you do so, you lose some accuracy. Unfortunately this number exceeds even `uint64` size and numba does not support `uint128` (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html), so you cannot do it using numba.